# How to test refinery sessions controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, refinery

I've overridden Refinery's session controller and not even modified it yet, as I'm trying to write some specs for it.

The controller lives in app/controllers/refinery/sessions_controller:

```
module Refinery
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  ....
  def create                 
      super
      rescue ::BCrypt::Errors::InvalidSalt, ::BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash
      flash[:error] = t('password_encryption', :scope => 'refinery.users.forgot')
      redirect_to refinery.new_refinery_user_password_path
  end
  .....
```

I then am trying to write a spec against this in spec/controllers/refinery/sessions_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
  describe Refinery::SessionsController do
    it "should post ok" do
      post :create
      response.should be_success 
    end     
  end
```

However this is giving me an error

```
No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"refinery/sessions"}
```

This confuses me as when I run rake routes, I get the following line:

```
 refinery_user_session POST    /refinery/users/login(.:format)              refinery/sessions#create
```

Could anyone help?

Rails 3.2.8, refinery 2.0.8